# Who determine GLIBCXX_version when build a binary using g++?

Tags: c++, g++, centos6, libstdc++

I am building an self-made shared library using **G++ 4.9.3** on **Centos 6.8.**

This library uses boost::interprocess::file_lock and version of **boost** is **1.41.0.**

I am not working on multiple environment.. I just use a device and I've never changed build environment after I built the library.

When I build library, g++ build it well. But when I run it by linking with an binary, it shows 
**"./a.out: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./libmylib.so)"**.

So, I checked which versions supported by the libstdc++ and it show it doesn't support GLIBCXX upper than 3.4.13.
GLIBCXX_3.4.13 is the latest version of /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 supports.

Even though I am working on a device and its libstdc++ doesn't support GLIBCXX_3.4.15, the library build from my device requires GLIBCXX_3.4.15.

And another binaries doesn't require GLIBCXX_3.4.15 even if I use same compiler(g++4.9.3). They just work well.

How can the library notice it should use GLIBCXX_3.4.15?

Is it differed by source code?

Does compiler tell the library such as "you require to use GLIBCXX_3.4.15 because you use some special grammar in your code"?

**I want know who determine which version of GLIBCXX to use for a binary.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the version of GCC, the compiler flags, and the source code.  Symbols such as `GLIBCXX_3.4.15` are only referenced if a specific feature is used in a program.  The list of features for this particular symbol version is rather large.  You can get a sense of what features are relevant using this command (which you have to run against the *newer* libstdc++, i.e. the one that comes with GCC 4.9):

```
$ readelf -sW libstdc++.so.6 | awk '/@GLIBCXX_3.4.15/{print $8}' \
  | sort -u \
  | c++filt
```

If you want to run your program with the unmodified `libstdc++.so.6` version that comes with Red Hat Enterprise Linux or CentOS, you can use [Developer Toolset](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/) (which is also available [as a supported part of Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_toolset/).  Developer Toolset avoids dependencies on newer symbol versions by using the old (C++98 era) C++ ABI and providing statically linked copies of functions which are not part of the system libstdc++ version for the particular target operating system version.

Comment: I used the command on my library and it show std::out_of_range uses GLIBCXX_3.4.15. And std::out_of_range seems used by boost library.
Your answer is really helpful! Thank you!